# Display contents of a word file that is stored in Firebase database by clicking a CardView in a Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a Book App project in which the book will have chapters and the chapter names will be shown on a CardView.

I will be using Android studio and Java.

I wanted to know how to display contents of a word file or any other text file that is stored in Firebase database by clicking a CardView in a Recyclerview.

Any insights would be great. I want to know whether it is possible and any way on how to go about it would be great.

I have researched a bit, but all i could find was how to display name, age, image or any other data that has to be first entered/uploaded by the user which would be stored in the firebase database then it could be displayed in the recycler view.

Comment: It's definitely possible. Have you tried something so far?

Comment: not yet, im trying to find out the best way possible to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to read a plain text file in Java. you can use
**FileReader**, **BufferedReader**, or **Scanner** to read a text file.

**BufferedReader Example:**

So you will have to retrieve the text file from firebase and store it in device and do the following

```
  // File path is passed as parameter
    File file = new File(
        "link_of_the_file");

    // Note:  Double backquote is to avoid compiler
    // interpret words
    // like \test as \t (ie. as a escape sequence)

    // Creating an object of BufferedReader class
    BufferedReader br
        = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    // Declaring a string variable
    String st;
    // Condition holds true till
    // there is character in a string
    while ((st = br.readLine()) != null)

        // Print the string
        System.out.println(st);
```